# TFS 2010 user can't connect to TFS when opening a solution: TFS http://... is currently unavailable

Tags: tfs

I have a group of students connecting to Team Foundation Server.  When they connect from school, when their computers are physically on the network, they can successfully access TFS and perform get operations, checkout, checkin, etc.

The same users go home, install VS 2010, connect to TFS, get the code, but the solution will be opened offline from TFS.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the students are at home, do they access the server from a different name than they do at school?  Often, users will use a short (not fully qualified) name to access a server internally.  For example:

```
http://tfsserver:8080/
```

However, this will not work from outside of the network, the name will need to be fully-qualified.  For example:

```
http://tfsserver.mycompany.com:8080/
```

The Visual Studio solution contains version control bindings that point to your Team Foundation Server.  If the users cannot access the server by name in the bindings, the solution will be opened offline.  The users should connect to Team Foundation Server and then select "Change Source Control" in the file menu.  This will cause the solution file to point to the fully-qualified domain name of the Team Foundation Server which should allow access from within your internal network or from the outside world.

Comment: So we checked - when they check that, there are no bindings
then when clicking "Bind" it says: The mappings for the solution could not be found.